# How to send React Native Camera captured image to Back-end Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, api, expo

I have captured an image with React Native (expo-app) and can't find a proper way to send it to backend, mostly 500 and 422 appears (422 at this example).

Here is how a image data looks

```
{"base64": null, "height": 820, "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/792E2665-5063-4853-876E-3793568C7FCF/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fexpo-app-27783a0c-0a97-44a6-be26-48d37639bb25/ImageManipulator/9FCEF372-7C90-484F-9028-7D4271F9978D.jpg", "width": 476}
```

Here is the axios request to the backend, a photo state contains the data of image like above

```
     const handleSubmit = async() => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("photo", {
          uri: photo.uri,
          name: photo.uri.split('/').pop(),
          type: 'image/jpg'
      });
      
        await axios.post("/api/upload", {
            formData
          }, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
          })
      }
```

Here is the laravel side, it can't go through validation

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'photo' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'successfuly executed',
    ]);
}
```

Here is the laravel err log of what was in the request, even though console logging in the front end right before sending request, an object of image exist.

```
{"formData": null}
```

I can't figure out how to upload or even get captured image to react back-end, any ideas?

Comment: [How to use FormData for AJAX file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Is the error happening with Android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

```
await axios.post("/api/upload", 
        formData
      , {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
```

remove brackets and try again

Answer (score 0):

This image URI -  `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/792E2665-5063-4853-876E-3793568C7FCF/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fexpo-app-27783a0c-0a97-44a6-be26-48d37639bb25/ImageManipulator/9FCEF372-7C90-484F-9028-7D4271F9978D.jpg` is a reference to image data on device memory but not actually image data.

`expo-image-picker` returns `base64` image data and you can upload them to your server.